# nginx' try_files doesn't work with variables from location pattern captures

Tags: nginx

if i have a location directive with named captures:

```
location ~ ^/api/(?<endpoint>[^/]+)(?<pathinfo>.*) {
    root /opt/software/endpoints;
    ## breaks the config:
    # try_files $endpoint.php =418;
    include fastcgi_params; # as supplied by debian 8 "jessie"
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/$endpoint.php;
}
```

without the try_files, calling the correct url does invoke the php-file and returns the output.

```
curl -s http://example.com/api/foo/param
> output of foo.php with param "param"
```

but when i also activate try_files in the config, the curl always returns 418.

(the reason is, that i want to specify an internal redirect, in case no such endpoint exists, as last parameter to try_files. but i think =418 demonstrates the puzzlement better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should capture the leading slash. `nginx` URIs have a leading slash so your `try_files` directive (as you have it) will always fail. You have added the slash back in with your `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` directive.

Try this:

```
location ~ ^/api(?<endpoint>/[^/]+)(?<pathinfo>.*) {
    root /opt/software/endpoints;
    try_files $endpoint.php =418;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$endpoint.php;
}
```

Comment: the minimal config posted here did work with the slash added.  
however, my real config still didn't work.  
try_files was executing with the nginx user, which didn't have permission on the /opt/software/ directory. but php5-fpm did.

Comment: Are you sure it enters this location? Could there be a conflicting location block? See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) regarding order of precedence.